# How to checkout multiple repos in single jenkins workspace

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, svn-checkout

How to checkout multiple repos in single jenkins workspace. I am using SVN as my scm

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a different folder for different repositories inside single workspace, you can use **ws(yourlocalfolderpath)**{ checkout{} } for every repository you want to checkout.
Here, **yourlocalfolderpath** should be the folder name you want to create inside your single workspace. Like this, you can create folders for multiple repos in a single workspace.